# gnuplot - minor tics not appearing

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I have this code, wehre I use gnuplot and latex in math mode:

> set log
>
> set xtics ('$1$' 1, '$10$' 10, '$10^2$' 100, '$10^3$' 1000, '$10^4$' 10000)
>
> set ytics ('$10^{\textrm{-}7}$' 0.0000001, '$10^{\textrm{-}6}$' 0.000001)
>
> set mytics 10
>
> set mxtics 10
>
> p "datafile.dat" u 5:4 w l lw 2 lc 1 title 'total'

It is part of a multiplot plot and since the ranges and tics must be very different in every single plot, I use unset xtics and unset ytics between plots.

Minor tics never appear. I have tried with set xtics add (...) and set ytics add (...) insetad of the simple set to no avail, nothing changes. I have tried removing the unset xtics and unset ytics, nothing changes.

I use gnuplot 4.4 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the minor tics doesn't work in your case, because you have only user-defined. It works, if you replace some of the automatic tics with your changes ones using `set xtics add`:

```
set log
set xrange[1:10000]
set tics format '$%g$'
set xtics add ('$10^2$' 100, '$10^3$' 1000, '$10^4$' 10000)
plot x
```

Note: I tested this with 4.4.4 (works) and 4.2.6 (doesn't work)

Comment: Great. It works perfectly if you are not in multiplot. In the multiplot, this was the second (upper-right) figure of four, and it does not. But it does if I switch the order of figures, probably owing to some overlapping of instructions.

Comment: @martina Maybe, but its hard to tell from your description.